# "Asking is currently unavailable" layout and probable text issue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, error-message

There was an outage across all stackexchange networks, and the site was in read only mode. I know stackexchange team is working on the issues and trying to get the site back up. I am not asking about the outage at all.

During outage, when I clicked "Ask Question" button, I was presented with a screen like this.

> [image]

Please see below points

1. As I annotated in the image, there is a line below "Asking is currently unavailable" header, and the description starts right after that line. Shouldn't there be bit more padding?
2. The text says "Asking is currently unavailable". English is not my first language, but somehow that sentence doesn't sound right.

Comment: As a native American English speaker, "asking is currently unavailable" reads just fine to me.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom "Asking questions is currently unavailable" is more correct English (as a native UK English speaker). "asking is currently unavailable" -> asking what? A question? To leave the room? ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live after our next production build.

Comment: That's a bit difficult for us to test... ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator you can test on http://stackoverflow.com/captcha the problem was i set a margin-bottom: 0 to .subheader class to make homepage and question listing page look neat with the listings. but since we use .subheader on a lot of pages, it causes 0 gap between header and content below. I have since limited the margin-bottom: 0 only on homepage and /questions page. other pages should have proper gap now.

Comment: @Deduplicator yep. once the fix is on live that should be fixed. it's related to the bug you reported.